# Discord.JS Error: Cannot find module at, Object.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

[image: Getting this error and I am not sure why.]

I am not to sure what this error is trying to show me. I am not very good at NodeJS haha.

[image: directory]

Comment: Can we see your directory?

Comment: The path you provided is incorrect or does not exist

Comment: Just added directory

Comment: Please don't upload images of code/errors, they should be formatted as codeblocks

Comment: So `commands` directory @Nullified

Comment: To expand on MrMythical's comment, please read "[Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527)"